# Organize Numerically Descending then Alphabetically Ascending by Different Elements in a List Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list with three elements in the following format:

```
[('ABC', 'DEF', 2), ('GHI', 'JKL', 6), ('MNO', 'PQR', 22), ('ABC', 'STU', 2)...]
```

I would like to sort by last element numerically. Then by first element alphabetically. Lastly by the second element if there is a tie. So my output would be:

```
[('MNO', 'PQR', 22), ('GHI', 'JKL', 6), ('ABC', 'DEF', 2), ('ABC', 'STU', 2)...]
```

I've tried

```
list_name.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

This only sorts by the last elements descending. How do I add the implement sorting the first and second element in that order alphabetically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return a tuple, and negate the number instead of using `reverse`:

```
list_name.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[2],) + x[:2])
```

This returns `(-item3, item1, item2)` and sorting takes place first by the integer `item3` in *descending* order, when tied on the number sorting is done on `item1` (alphabetically, ascending order), then on `item2`.

In effect, tuples are sorted in lexicographical order.

Demo:

```
>>> list_name = [('ABC', 'DEF', 2), ('GHI', 'JKL', 6), ('MNO', 'PQR', 22), ('ABC', 'STU', 2)]
>>> list_name.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[2],) + x[:2])
>>> list_name
[('MNO', 'PQR', 22), ('GHI', 'JKL', 6), ('ABC', 'DEF', 2), ('ABC', 'STU', 2)]
```

Comment: This sorts element 1 and 2 in a descending order, I need the first and second element in an ascending order and the third descending

Comment: No, element 1 and 2 are sorted in *ascending* order. Note the output produced. I did state you need to drop the `reverse` argument.

Comment: Element 0 is sorted in descending order only because the number is negated; -22 is sorted before -6 is sorted before -2.

Answer (score -2):

Just convert everything into a string and then compare ..

```
list_name.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: '%6d%s%s'%(x[2],x[0],x[1]) )
```

Comment: This would sort `10` after `9` instead of before (lexicographically instead of numerically), and sorts elements 1 and 2 in descending order.

Comment: Actually it would not. Thats why we add the zeros in the front.

Comment: Right, so it'll sort 1000000 after 9 then. There is *no need* to use a string when a tuple will do, and you are still sorting the two other components in the wrong order.

Comment: reversing the order of the numerical values is easily done by subtracting from the largest value in the list. For eg. `maxVal = numpy.array([x[2] for x in list_name]).max()` and `'%6d%s%s'%((maxVal-x[2]),x[0],x[1]) `

Comment: For a given value of 'easily'; you did incremented the complexity from O(NlogN) to O(2NlogN) there, of course.

Comment: And to follow up on this; you also make the assumption that all the strings are of equal length; concatenating them would lead to *entirely* different sorting results if they are not. Yes, you could pad them, but you'll only find more and more edge cases (such as supporting control bytes) that are all entirely avoided by returning a tuple from the sort key function instead.